# Canon printer & scanner (MP190) install on linux mint 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, printing

This question was solved earlier, but unfortunately the PPA used there no longer works on 20.04. Anyone have up to date information on how to bring a canon pixma MP190 printer to life on 64 bit linux over 20.04? Please help me!

By default it detects, the system adds it automatically, I print the test page, it says it's done, but no reaction from the printer, it doesn't move. It's the same with scanners.

Comment: Check the system logs, I remember having to deal with a similar issue a few months ago, also with Mint. I just can't recall what exactly I had to do, but you should see some errors pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what error log I am looking for? Or simply in system.log?
(on the weekend I might have a printer and a laptop and then I'll do a debugging)

Comment: No, I don't remember and it was not my system. `syslog` would be the first choice, and then maybe also in cups.log, it's probably in `/var/log/cups`.